# Can I restore an iPhone 5S Backup with 7.0.4 on to my iOS 8.3 iPod Touch 5G?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, ipod, restore

My iPod touch got stuck in a screen and it says to connect to iTunes, and the only backup I have is an iPhone 5S 7.0.4 backup. I don't want to break anything. Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works fine. Device backups are interchangeable between device models, including iPad ⇔ iPhone.

Comment: so this means the iOS version would also downgrade? I don't want any bugged apps...

Comment: @Slothiac No, backups only restore content and settings, not iOS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the short answer to your question is no, but I have a solution that should be workable to solve your problem.  First of all, you may be able to restore an iPhone backup to an iPod or vice-versa, but this is not going to fix the issue.  To expound on the rest: Apple no longer supports the SHSH blob files that used to be usable to restore to older firmware.  In a short window of opportunity upon each new release Apple continues "signing" the prior version of the firmware in case you don't like the new one or have trouble with it.  This is the only possibility for downgrading that I'm aware of at this point. Usually this window of opportunity is only a month or maybe a couple of weeks.

To solve your problem let me first describe the issue: You have found your iPod in one of the following states: DFU (device firmware update) mode, or Recovery Mode.  You have a couple of options to get it out of this state.

1. Use the reboot button combo (press/hold both the *Sleep* button & the *Home* button for about 10-15 seconds).  Once the Apple logo appears, let go.
2. If that doesn't work, download and use a well-known tool called TinyUmbrella. You can find it [here](http://blog.firmwareumbrella.com/).  You attach your iPod to the system with the usb cable.  Exit iTunes & start up TinyUmbrella.  When you open TinyUmbrella it detects the device you have in DFU or Recovery mode.  You can select it and then click the "Exit Recovery" or "Exit DFU Mode" button.  Your device should reboot and start up normally.
3. You can attempt to restore the firmware to the latest version through iTunes, potentially losing everything that you've got on it.  Let me know if you need a quick refresher on how that's done.

It seems people have found that restoring one device's backup to an entirely different one is possible, but this actually is not recommended due to the variations in settings per device.  If you do attempt this, you should go to Settings->General->Reset->Reset All Settings to be sure that you don't end up with some weird bugs due to your other device's settings being on there.

Even if you are successful in restoring the backup, this doesn't actually include the OS firmware.  So you aren't likely to get your iPod out of the mode it's in just by restoring a backup.

Comment: Restoring from backup installs the current version of iOS, so restoring from a backup should theoretically wipe the OS and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes.

The restore process upgrades your device to the latest version of iOS, so the fact it's a backup from an older version shouldn't cause problems. There is nothing that should cause permanent damage to your device by trying.

That said, I would follow @JasonCramer's steps of trying to get it out of DFU mode first before attempting to restore a backup.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a backup from your iPod to your iPhone you will have problems, because the Apple's script is not accepting iOS minor than 8 right now (That's called downgrade). But if want to make an "Upgrade" so you have no problem with that, and it will work even with different devices.

Comment: Backups are iOS-version agnostic.